# Sufficient criterion for unit distance graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

There are many necessary criteria for a graph to be a unit distance graph. For example, it must not have $K_4$ as a subgraph etc. Can we find some  sufficient criterion for a graph to be a unit distance graph?
This may be useful to prove/disprove that some well-known graphs are unit-distance graphs, say Petersen graph, odd graphs etc.

Comment: For completeness, from WIkipedia *"a unit distance graph is a graph formed from a collection of points in the Euclidean plane by connecting two points by an edge whenever the distance between the two points is exactly one"*.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.07829

Comment: A necessary and sufficient condition is unlikely: Schaefer, Marcus (2013), "Realizability of graphs and linkages", in Pach, János (ed.), Thirty Essays on Geometric Graph Theory, Springer, pp. 461–482, doi:10.1007/978-1-4614-0110-0_24

Comment: I also agree, however, it may not be very hard  to find only some useful sufficient criterion.